# Awesome wibox: remove tag label

Tags: awesome

Currently, I have both the gajim and skype windows visible as both icons (in systray) and window labels (in mytasklist).  How can I remove that latter so that it is not shown since I do not need two instances of the same thing cluttering my wibox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a window not appear in the tasklist, you have to set `skip_taskbar` to `true` for the client.
As you want to do that for specific applications, probably the best way is to add a client rule to your `rc.lua`:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    { rule = { class = {"Gajim","Skype"} },
      properties = { skip_taskbar = true }
    },
    -- other rules ...
}
```

You may have to change the values for `class`. To get the window class of a X program, call `xprop WM_CLASS` from a terminal, then click on the window you want to match. This should output 2 values (e.g. `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Zsh", "URxvt"`). The second one is the one for `class`. The first one can be matched with `instance` and may be used to differentiate between windows from the same program.

See also [Awesome Wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Understanding_Rules) for more on rules and [Awesome API docs](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/client.html#client) for a list of properties you can set with rules.